# An error occurred uploading to the app store with no error code

Tags: xcode, application-loader

Just updated to XCode 9. Trying to upload the build to iTunes Connect but getting an error:

[image: Error]

No error code is displayed. Have anyone dealt with this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same problem this morning, you can try to open the terminal and run these commands:

```
cd ~
mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/
```

It worked for me.

Comment: This worked! However I would be glad if you explained how you figured this out and what the command does. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Preferences > Network > Advanced > Proxies and make sure "Auto Proxy Discovery" and "Automatic Proxy Configuration" are checked but none of the other proxy options are checked. I had to uncheck "SOCKS Proxy" option to resolve the issue. [Found this solution in a comment of this thread.](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123649#389459)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that helped me was to use Transporter (from the Mac App Store: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12). Export with the export button on the failure panel to a directory. Login, then open the *.ipa with Transporter and the upload works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using XCode 9.0 and ionic 3.15. Loegic's commands worked for me to get things started.

```
cd ~
mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/
```

At which point I got another error when trying to upload to the app store again.

```
ERROR ITMS-90717: "Invalid App Store Icon. The App Store Icon in the asset catalog in 'APP_NAME' can't be transparent nor contain an alpha channel."
```

So I removed transparency from the icon and it worked. Well it would have been nice to know that in the first place! Another example that Apple and XCode are trash. Don't support Apple products.